Where to put acknowledgments in a math paper
I have seen acknowledgments in math papers in two locations: at the end of the introduction, and at the end just before the bibliography. Which location is preferred and why?

I suspect it depends on the particular journal's format.

Unless a journal has a preference, either is fine. The important thing is to include it, not its location.
Including it early gives a bit of immediate context to a reader, but probably not enough to affect their later reading.
However, if the ack section is extensive, it might be better at the end so as to avoid interrupting the flow.

Unless a journal has a preference - This makes it sound like most math journals don't have preferences, but my very unscientific impression was that most do.  (In fact I was a bit disoriented by one journal where sometimes the acknowledgements would be in the intro and sometimes not.)

The purpose of the acknowledgements is, well, to acknowledge people who helped you — also in the sense of making those people feel acknowledged. Now ask yourself, if you were being acknowledged in a colleague’s paper, would you feel more acknowledged if you saw your name mentioned in the  introduction, a relatively heavily-trafficked part of the paper, or at the very end of the paper, a part of the paper that many readers never get to?
Conclusion: putting the acknowledgements in the introduction makes them more prominent, and is generally preferable. If I was acknowledging an abusive adviser who didn’t help me at all but where for some reason I felt compelled to acknowledge them, I might bury the acknowledgements at the end of the paper. But I can’t think of other situations where that would seem like the better choice. (Edit: well, one such possible situation is if the paper is very short. In that case, it probably doesn’t matter where you put the acknowledgements.)

I also prefer at the end of the intro, and I would add that most readers don't get beyond the introduction, let alone to the end of the paper.
